Is there a way to trigger a dash plotly callback any time a user clicks enter (Python)?
I have this button:
dbc.Button(
    "DO SOMETHING",
    color="primary",
    id="button1",
    autofocus = True,
    
    n_clicks=int(0),
    size="lg",
    className="mb-4 w-100",
),

Which triggers the following function:
def init_callbacks(self):
    @self.app.callback(
        Output("dashboard1", "data"),
        [Input("button1", "n_clicks")],
        [
            State("selectbook", "value"),
            State("date1", "value"),
            State("ticker", "value"),
            State("ticker_filter", "value"),
            State("instrument_type_filter", "value"),
        ],
    )
    @log_callback(logger)
    def initialize_table(
        n_clicks: int,
        book: str,
        date: str,
        strategy_filter: str,
        ticker_filter: str,
        instrument_type_filter: str,
    ) -> list:

Is there a way to trigger the button any time the user clicks enter on the screen?
I have so far tried autofocus with n_submit but have not managed to make it work.
